# Soundcloud Widget API how to change the playlist?

Tags: soundcloud

How can I modify the current Soundcloud Widget API so I can listen to some other playing or track?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'load' method described here

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget